# pandas data reader google finance for australian stock exchange

Tags: python, pandas

Unable to get quotes from google finance using pandas and the new data reader module for tickers specifically on the australian stock exchange.

the relevant google finance page for each stock lists them as:
commonwealth bank asx:cba
billabong international asx:bbg etc

however pandas datareader does not except the ticker in format asx:stock_code such as asx:cba

```
import pandas
from pandas_datareader import data
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 27)
end = datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 27)
f = web.DataReader('bbg:asx', 'google', start, end)
```

[pandas datareader module on github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader)
pandas datareader functionality is now separated from pandas library itself
[pandas datareader read the docs](http://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

What syntax must be used so the google finance module of pandas datareader returns a pandas dataframe of stock prices for an australian stock on the ASX?

Answer (score 0):

Google Finance, as Yahoo Finance, places some limits on data offered through their website available via `GET` request. You can see that for `ASX:BBG` (and other `ASX` stocks), the `'export to spreadsheet'` option is missing on the `historical prices` site (compare to `NASDAQ:GOOGL`, for instance).

You can also check that the ticker syntax `ASX:BBG` is correct using:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.google.com/finance/historical'
params = {'q': 'ASX:BBG'}
r = requests.get(url=url, params=params)

pd.read_html(r.content)[2]
```

which yields the first 30 of the paginated results:

```
               0     1     2     3      4       5
0           Date  Open  High   Low  Close  Volume
1   May 27, 2016  1.44  1.46  1.40   1.46       0
2   May 26, 2016  1.36  1.48  1.36   1.46       0
3   May 25, 2016  1.38  1.40  1.36   1.38       0
4   May 24, 2016  1.38  1.39  1.35   1.38       0
5   May 23, 2016  1.33  1.42  1.32   1.42       0
6   May 20, 2016  1.33  1.35  1.32   1.33       0
7   May 19, 2016  1.39  1.40  1.33   1.34       0
8   May 18, 2016  1.38  1.40  1.37   1.39       0
9   May 17, 2016  1.36  1.38  1.36   1.38       0
10  May 16, 2016  1.38  1.38  1.32   1.36       0
11  May 13, 2016  1.36  1.40  1.35   1.38       0
12  May 12, 2016  1.33  1.38  1.33   1.36       0
13  May 11, 2016  1.32  1.39  1.32   1.35       0
14  May 10, 2016  1.26  1.33  1.26   1.32       0
15   May 9, 2016  1.30  1.32  1.27   1.27       0
16   May 6, 2016  1.30  1.32  1.28   1.32       0
17   May 5, 2016  1.31  1.31  1.28   1.30       0
18   May 4, 2016  1.30  1.32  1.26   1.30       0
19   May 3, 2016  1.32  1.33  1.24   1.32       0
20   May 2, 2016  1.36  1.36  1.29   1.33       0
21  Apr 29, 2016  1.32  1.37  1.30   1.36       0
22  Apr 28, 2016  1.35  1.36  1.28   1.30       0
23  Apr 27, 2016  1.38  1.40  1.34   1.36       0
24  Apr 26, 2016  1.40  1.41  1.37   1.38       0
25  Apr 22, 2016  1.42  1.43  1.41   1.42       0
26  Apr 21, 2016  1.44  1.46  1.42   1.42       0
27  Apr 20, 2016  1.48  1.48  1.42   1.46       0
28  Apr 19, 2016  1.48  1.52  1.44   1.46       0
29  Apr 18, 2016  1.50  1.52  1.48   1.48       0
30  Apr 15, 2016  1.50  1.54  1.49   1.50       0
```

Hence, you could modify `params` like this

```
from datetime import date
params = {'q': 'ASX:BBG', 'startdate':date(2016,4,1), 'enddate':date(2016,5,1)}
```

to iterate through the different time periods:

```
               0     1     2     3      4       5
0           Date  Open  High   Low  Close  Volume
1   Apr 29, 2016  1.32  1.37  1.30   1.36       0
2   Apr 28, 2016  1.35  1.36  1.28   1.30       0
3   Apr 27, 2016  1.38  1.40  1.34   1.36       0
4   Apr 26, 2016  1.40  1.41  1.37   1.38       0
5   Apr 22, 2016  1.42  1.43  1.41   1.42       0
6   Apr 21, 2016  1.44  1.46  1.42   1.42       0
7   Apr 20, 2016  1.48  1.48  1.42   1.46       0
8   Apr 19, 2016  1.48  1.52  1.44   1.46       0
9   Apr 18, 2016  1.50  1.52  1.48   1.48       0
10  Apr 15, 2016  1.50  1.54  1.49   1.50       0
11  Apr 14, 2016  1.50  1.54  1.48   1.52       0
12  Apr 13, 2016  1.47  1.52  1.47   1.48       0
13  Apr 12, 2016  1.49  1.54  1.46   1.48       0
14  Apr 11, 2016  1.50  1.54  1.46   1.54       0
15   Apr 8, 2016  1.51  1.52  1.48   1.50       0
16   Apr 7, 2016  1.52  1.56  1.52   1.54       0
17   Apr 6, 2016  1.59  1.60  1.51   1.52       0
18   Apr 5, 2016  1.66  1.66  1.58   1.60       0
19   Apr 4, 2016  1.78  1.80  1.66   1.68       0
20   Apr 1, 2016  1.81  1.82  1.76   1.77       0
```